# Azure Worker failed on executing long running operation

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have a few roles running in my web app. They are communicating via Azure Storage Queue messages between them. It means that Web role places message, after that worker role catch it and start executing.

Mainly, Worker role work with files. It remove all empty rows in xlsx files. 
Worker iterate all rows and cells within every rows. So if all cells within rows empty I remove row.

It work perfectly for file with total rows less than 100 000, but one of our customer loaded file with 1 100 000 records (1 098 800 are empty). So when worker's processing it is failed. See attached picture.

I attached debugger to this process. And my breakpoints fired first 30-40 seconds in loop. But after that debugger detached and I see the message in azure portal, that worker unhealthy.

I also tried to execute file processing method in separate thread. But have the same result.

Any ideas?

[image]

UPDATE:

My Run method looks like

```
public override void Run() {
    var queue = GetCloudQueue();
    int maxJobRetries = 10;
    while (true) {
        try {
            var msg = queue.GetMessage();

            if (msg != null) {
                if (msg.DequeueCount <= maxJobRetries) {
                    ImportCommand ic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < ImportCommand > (msg.AsString);
                    ProcessImport(queue, msg);
                } else {
                    queue.DeleteMessage();
                }
            } else {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

I really don't think that there are any unhandled exception can be thrown. I put all my code in try catch block.

I think it's worth to mention that I use Gembox to parse xlsx files. My parsing method looks:

```
    public IEnumerable < string[] > ReadLines(int sheetIndex) {
    string[] data = null;
    if (_file.Worksheets.Count > 0 && _file.Worksheets[sheetIndex].Rows.Count > 0) {
        if (_headerLength == 0) {
            _headerLength = _file.Worksheets[sheetIndex].Rows[0].AllocatedCells.Count;
        }
// I have great than 1 000 000 Rows
        foreach(ExcelRow row in _file.Worksheets[sheetIndex].Rows) {
            data = new string[_headerLength];
// I have 30 columns
            for (int j = 0; j < _headerLength ; j++) {
                ExcelCell cell = row.Cells[j];
                if (cell.Value != null) {
                    bool isDate = cell.Value is DateTime;
                    if (!isDate) {
                        data[j] = cell.Value.ToString();
                    } else {
                        //if locale is null then used CurrentCulture (.net feature)
                        data[j] = ((DateTime) cell.Value).ToString(_locale);
                    }
                } else {
                    data[j] = null;
                }
            }
            yield return data;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:

Thanks to David Makogon.
I change two size up (up to A2) and it's working now. But my memory spent in a minute. And its very expensive to keep A2. Any ideas how can I reduce my code to make it working on small instances?

[image]

Comment: Most likely your role is recycling because of an unhandled exception. Can you please include the code for your role's `OnStart` method?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to diagnose your issue with the tiny bit of info you provided, except for *one little detail*: Your worker role instances are A0, the smallest-possible VM size, with 768MB RAM (and shared CPU). So it's highly likely your app is running into a memory constraint.

Normally I'd post this as a comment, but you're dealing with million-row xls files, which sounds like a very memory-intensive task, and that it would be solved by running on larger VM's.